# How to display user current location in autocompletetextview android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating an android application in which I am using Google Place API to display auto complete suggestions in autocompletetextview. Everything is working fine as user enters something. I am getting suggestions from Google Place API but I want user current location to be selected in auto complete by default. How can I achieve this? Can someone help me ?

Comment: get current location geopoints and find current address from geopoints.

Comment: Store the values in arraylist then infllate in automcompleteview

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Comment: thank you @Rustam . your answer solved my problem .  i got the solution at http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/